# Flutter : Add Drag and drop anywhere widget in stack widget dynamically

Tags: android, flutter, dart

**How can we dynamically add drag and drop anywhere widget in flutter?**
Here is what I tried to implement. Suggest changes to solve the problem or suggest the proper method to implement it.

The problem I need to solve is that the canvasItemObj.x and canvasItemObj.y variables are updating according to t the dragUpdate. But the position of the widget is not updating. (**top** and **left** parameters of the **Positioned() widget**)

Here is the **CanvasItemProps** class for holding a widget and its properties.

```
class CanvasItemProps {
  Widget canvasItem;
  double x = 0, y = 0, dx, dy;
  double scale = 1;
  Color color;
  CanvasItemProps();
  CanvasItemProps.fromItem(this.canvasItem);
}
```

**canvasItemProps** holds the list of CanvasItemProps

```
List<CanvasItemProps> canvasItemProps = [];
```

I have a flatbutton which onPressed execute the following:

```
var canvasItemObj = CanvasItemProps();
canvasItemProps.add(canvasItemObj);

canvasItemObj.canvasItem = Positioned(
                  left: canvasItemObj.x,
                  top: canvasItemObj.y,
                  child: GestureDetector(
                    child: Text(
                      addTextController.text,
                      textScaleFactor: 5,
                    ),
                    onVerticalDragUpdate: (dragDetails) {
                      setState(() {
                        canvasItemObj.y = dragDetails.localPosition.dy;
                        canvasItemObj.x = dragDetails.localPosition.dx;
                      });
                    },

                  ));
              addTextController.text = "";
              setState(() {});
            },
```

In build function there is a Stack:

```
Stack(children:canvasItemProps.isEmpty()?
               Text("No Item"):
                getCanvasItem)
```

The following **getCanvasItem** function returns the list of widget to pass to the Stack widget

```
List<Widget> getCanvasItem() {
    List<Widget> list = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < canvasItemProps.length; i++) {
      list.add(canvasItemProps[i].canvasItem);
    }
    return list;
  }
```

On the other hand, this works fine when I am dealing with only one widget that is not dynamically added(x and y are two variables declared in the scope and are initialized to 0.)

```
double x=0,y=0;
```

widget is as follows:

```
Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(50, 100, 90, 100),
            color: Colors.yellow,
            child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
            top: y,
            left: x,
            child: GestureDetector(
              onVerticalDragUpdate: (v){
                setState(() {
                  x = v.localPosition.dx;
                  y = v.localPosition.dy;
                });
              },
              child:Text("Text"),
            )
          ),
            ],
          ),
          )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the Top and Left parameters are final so you cant change the values. But instead, you should reinitialize the positioned widget each time with the updated values.